# Can Sony Remote API client change still image format?

Tags: android, camera, sony

Sometimes it's a good idea to acquire raw / dng image from camera, not just a jpeg. E.g. it can be useful to play with white balance or exposure settings.
As far as I try to use Sony Remote API, I can acquire jpeg images only by using actTakePicture/awaitTakePicture API methods.
I know how to change image size, but not image file format itself.
Is there any possibility to acquire raw or dng file using Sony Remote API (possibly, by changing some settings by hands, it's not critical)?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try setting your camera to RAW+JPEG mode if you haven't already set it.
Also newer QX1, QX30 cameras support 'Still quality' API. 
Best Regards, Prem, Developer World team.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, the advise doesn't work. Neither RAW mode, nor RAW+JPEG mode. All uris that I get from ActTakePicture / AwaitTakePicture look like http:// (ip of the camera) /postview/camera/ (image name) .JPEG, no raw files are available.

Comment: p.S. Moreover, there are only jpeg images on SD card when taking pictures through API, no matter what mode was set on camera. It's inacceptable behavior. I'm disappointed with A7R.

Comment: p.p.S. Setting camera to RAW+JPEG in smart remote app menu eventually have allowed me to store raw images on SD. That's more than nothing. However, still cannot download them during remote control session. Return value expected - array of two urls (one to jpeg, one to raw). Return value actual - array of just one url, that's to jpeg (in other words, return value is like it was just jpeg session).